# Deployment content type on production using a wsp

Tags: content-type, solution-package

I've create a lot of custom content types in a Visual Studio Solution on the development environment. Everything works fine, and I deploy everything to the content type hub using Visual Studio (I've put everything in a feature and it's a feature with the 'site' scope).

Now when I wanna put my content types to the production environment, I decided to do this by publishing my solution as a wsp to my client machine, and install it on production using Powershell with the following commands

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath "C:\Solutions\mysolution.wsp"
Install-SPSolution –Identity "mysolution.wsp" –GACDeployment
```

After doing this, this solution is deployed globally (I see this in central administration) and the feature is available in my content type hub. But when I try to activate this feature (to create the content types on the content type hub in production) I get an error. When I take a look at the ULS logs this error is about **"Not enough information to determine a list for module . Assuming no list for this module."**

When I take a look at my content type XML code I guess it's about the following part

```
    <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="AlgemeneTemplate">
    <File Path="AlgemeneTemplate\PresentatieTemplate.pptx" Url="AlgemeneTemplate/PresentatieTemplate.pptx" ReplaceContent="TRUE" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

As far as I know the feature don't know where to store these document templates that I attached to my content type hub.

Now my question is: Do I need to add the solution as a SPUsersolution using Powershell to let this work, or am I doing it wrong in my elements file to be able using document templates?

Any help would be nice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it looks like I'm really close to the solution of this problem. Strange thing is that in my solution I'm using a module to include the templates. Here I define the module name and the file path as mentioned above, but in my content type I also have a module and file tag to 'link' it to the content type itself. Is there maybe a specific property I need to set to get this work? For example ghostable of ghostableinlibrary?